# How to return a class to Angular?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I want to return a class from Controller to angular

```
$scope.GetUser = function (user_id) {            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Menu/GetUser",
                data: '{"user_id":"' + user_id + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (resp) {
                    debugger
                },
                failure: function (resp) {
                    alert(resp);
                }
            });
        }
```

My controller

```
[HttpPost]
        //public JsonResult GetUser(string user_id)
        public User GetUser(string user_id)
        {
            return rep.GetUser(user_id);

            //return Json(new
            //{
            //    user = rep.GetUser(user_id)
            //}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

My model

```
public User GetUser(string user_id)
        {
            var user = ctx.tblUsuario.
                Where(x => x.usuario_id.Trim() == user_id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (user == null)
                return null;

            return new User(user.usuario_id, user.usuario_nome, user.usuario_perfilid, user.usuario_dtcadastro, user.usuario_senha);
        }
```

My class

```
namespace DB_Pro.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        private string Usuario_id { get; set; }
        private string Usuario_nome { get; set; }
        private int Usuario_perfilid { get; set; }
        private DateTime Usuario_dtcadastro { get; set; }
        private string Usuario_senha { get; set; }

        public User(string usuario_id, string usuario_nome, int usuario_perfilid, DateTime usuario_dtcadastro, string usuario_senha)
        {
            Usuario_id = usuario_id;
            Usuario_nome = usuario_nome;
            Usuario_perfilid = usuario_perfilid;
            Usuario_dtcadastro = usuario_dtcadastro;
            Usuario_senha = usuario_senha;
        }        
    }
}
```

But when I return to **success Ajax function**, it just have response
equals **"DB_Pro.Models.User"**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a json in your controller and send that to the angular controller?. That should really work and I see that you have the json creation commented in the controller.

The idea is that angular uses javascript objects and if you send that from the controller you should be able to access its contents easily.

In the json instead of placing the user, get its parameters,

name: u.NAME,
surname: u.SURNAME,
...

And from angular you cab directly access them. If you create a json with the user, angular will not know what a user is, that's why you are getting that response. Let the json be the user, an object with the parameters of the user, in this way when angular receives the data you just have to take then info that you need from data:

data.name
data.surname

**EDIT:**

After researching, I think this could work:

```
    [HttpPost]
    //public JsonResult GetUser(string user_id)
    public User GetUser(string user_id)
    {
        User u = rep.GetUser(user_id);
        var result = Json(new { Usuario_nome = u.Usuario_nome,
                                Usuario_perfilid = u.Usuario_perfilid});

        return result;

    }
```

Try it and tell me if it solves the problem

Comment: Thx dude. Could u show me a example please?
I try it
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user); 
But when I serialize returns null just
var json = {}

Comment: I really appreciate u for help me... It's work fine! I did another changes and work well too. Take a look....

Comment: Great! Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Thx a lot Davidivad to help me.
I also did some changes too and it worked well

My Model

```
public tblUsuario GetUser(string user_id)
    {
        return ctx.tblUsuario.
            Where(x => x.usuario_id == user_id).FirstOrDefault();

        //var user = ctx.tblUsuario.
        //    Where(x => x.usuario_id == user_id).FirstOrDefault();
        //if (user == null)
        //    return null;

        //return new User(user.usuario_id, user.usuario_nome, user.usuario_perfilid, user.usuario_dtcadastro, user.usuario_senha);
    }
```

My controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetUser(string user_id)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                user = rep.GetUser(user_id)
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to send any object through, you should serialize it to a stream (preferably JSON string).

because you dont serialize, your `return new User(...);` calls the default `.toString()` of your `User` class, which returns the type-name (in your case: `DB_Pro.Models.User`)